# Slider.Value changes on adjusting Minimum when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

**In short:**
Under certain circumstances setting Slider.Minimum will adjust Slider.Value although the current Value is bigger then the new Minimum.

**Code:** (should be reproducible)
*MainWindow.xaml:*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <Slider Name="MySlider" DockPanel.Dock="Top" AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" />
        <Button Name="MyButton1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="shrink borders"/>
        <Button Name="MyButton2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="grow borders"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs:*

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MySlider.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Value changed: " + e.NewValue);
            };

            System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Slider.MinimumProperty, typeof(Slider)).AddValueChanged(MySlider, delegate
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Minimum changed: " + MySlider.Minimum);
            });

            System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Slider.MaximumProperty, typeof(Slider)).AddValueChanged(MySlider, delegate
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Maximum changed: " + MySlider.Maximum);
            });

            MySlider.Value = 1;

            MySlider.Minimum = 0.5;
            MySlider.Maximum = 20;

            MyButton1.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                MySlider.Minimum = 1.6;
                MySlider.Maximum = 8;
            };

            MyButton2.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                MySlider.Minimum = 0.5;
                MySlider.Maximum = 20;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce:**
1. Run in Debug mode.
2. Move Slider to the far right.
3. Press "shrink borders" Button.
4. Press "grow borders" Button.

**Expected Output:**

```
Value changed: 1
Minimum changed: 0,5
Maximum changed: 20
//Multiple times "Value changed"
Value changed: 20
Minimum changed: 1,6
Value changed: 8
Maximum changed: 8
Minimum changed: 0,5
Maximum changed: 20
```

Slider stays at 8.

**Actual Output:**

```
Value changed: 1
Minimum changed: 0,5
Maximum changed: 20
//Multiple times "Value changed"
Value changed: 20
Minimum changed: 1,6
Value changed: 8
Maximum changed: 8
Value changed: 1
Minimum changed: 0,5
Maximum changed: 20
```

(Note the additional "Value changed: 1")
Slider jumps to 1.

**Sidenote:**
Binding Slider.Value OneWayToSource (or TwoWay) to a double property, fixes the issue.

**Question:**
Why is this happening?

**Theory:**
I'm pretty sure it has something to do with [Value Coercion](http://drwpf.com/blog/2010/05/05/value-coercion-for-the-masses/). It seems like the following happens:
1. Setting Value to 1 programmatical sets Value's "base value". It is between the default values for Minimum and Maximum, so the "effective value" is exactly the same.
2. Setting Minimum and Maximum does not change anything, because Value is still in between them.
3. Manually pulling the Slider to the right apparently changes the "effective value" but for some weird reason not the "base value".
4. Increasing the borders again, calls the coercion callback, which realizes, that the (wrong) "base value" is between the new Minimum and Maximum and changes the "effective value" back to it.

Assuming this is indeed what is happening, leads us to the following question:
Why is manually pulling the Slider (3.) not affecting the "base value"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what the use case is, but this issue could probably be avoided if you were using MVVM and everything was bound.  If that's what you're doing and this is just another way you're reproducing the issue, good find.

Take a look at the [`Slider` source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Slider.cs).  I couldn't pinpoint the issue, but I have a better understanding that there is an internal value being used.

Add 2 buttons, and only change Minimum or Maximum in the event handlers for all buttons:

```
MyButton1.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    MySlider.Minimum = 1.6;
};

MyButton2.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    MySlider.Minimum = 0.5;
};

MyButton3.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    MySlider.Maximum = 20;
};

MyButton4.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    MySlider.Maximum = 8;
};
```

At startup, click `MyButton1` and `MyButton2`:

```
Value changed: 1.6
Minimum changed: 1.6
Value changed: 1
Minimum changed: 0.5
Value changed: 1.6
Minimum changed: 1.6
Value changed: 1
Minimum changed: 0.5
```

You can see, internally, it stores the original start value and restores it when the range is capable of showing it, it sets it back to what it was.  If you change only the maximum's at startup (without moving slider bar), the `Value` property isn't changed because the `Value` is in the current range:

```
Maximum changed: 8
Maximum changed: 20
Maximum changed: 8
Maximum changed: 20
```

However, when you change the slider bar maximum to 20, then change the `Maximum = 8` and `Minimum = 1.6`, the `Minimum` is now out of range from (internal) `Value` (1)  and uses the `Maximum` value for it's `Value`.  When you grow it again, you set `Minimum = 0.5` and `Maximum = 20`, and since the internal value = 1 and is between 0.5 and 20, it sets the `Value` back to 1.

I found one workaround, and that is resetting the internal value every time you change the range.  To reset, you just set the `Slider.Value` again.  If you do this after you change the `Maximum` and `Minimum` it will persist the value in the event the old value isn't in the range of the new range.  So taking your initial implementation:

```
MyButton1.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    MySlider.Minimum = 1.6;
    MySlider.Maximum = 8;
    MySlider.Value = MySlider.Value;
};

MyButton2.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    MySlider.Minimum = 0.5;
    MySlider.Maximum = 20;
    MySlider.Value = MySlider.Value;
};
```

**Output (matches your expected):**

```
Value changed: 1
Minimum changed: 0.5
Maximum changed: 20
//Multiple times "Value changed"
Value changed: 20
Minimum changed: 1.6
Value changed: 8
Maximum changed: 8
Minimum changed: 0.5
Maximum changed: 20
```

### Edit

The link you posted about value coercion is very helpful.  I'm not sure if your question would be considered a second question, but I believe I found the answer.

When you use the `Slider` (technically the `Thumb` with the `Track`), realize that the `Thumb` sliding around is bound to the `Slider.Value`through  [`Slider.UpdateValue`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/e804f0ead88d96c9.html) gets called.  This issue now is that `SetCurrentValueInternal` is not open source :(  What we can conclude is that the mystery function isn't coercing `ValueProperty`, instead it's only setting the base ("desired") value.  Try:

```
private void MyButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MySlider.Minimum = 1.6;
    MySlider.Maximum = 8;
    MySlider.CoerceValue(Slider.ValueProperty); //Set breakpoint, watch MySlider.Value before and after breakpoint.
}
```

Doing the above you will see that even though `Value` will go from 20 down to 8, the second you actually Coerce ValueProperty when it drops down to 8, the value will then change to `1.6`.  In fact, that's what happens when you grow the range.  After you set Max or Min you will see the Value change since it is coercing value property again. Try flipping Max and Min:

```
private void MyButton2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MySlider.Maximum = 20; //Will change Value to 1.6 after executing
    MySlider.Minimum = 0.5; //Will change Value to 1 after executing
}
```

Still, this makes you think, how can it remember to go back to 1 when possible, is there an effective, base, and initial values?  I'm not sure.

Matter of fact try this.

1. Start application
2. Move thumb all the way to right (Value = 20)
3. Shrink borders (Value = 8)
4. Take thumb and move it to the left, then all the way to the right (Value = 8)
5. Then grow borders

After step 5 you will observe that Value still equals 8.  This is how I found out that its something to do with that mystery function.

Note: My brain is dead again, so if this isn't clear, I apologize, I'll have to come back and edit it.

### Edit 2

For one, both `SetCurrentValueInteral` and `SetValue` both call `SetValueCommon`.  The difference is `SetCurrentValueInternal` re-evaluates the current value with the base value since the coerce flag is set to true. (keeps the value in-bounds of Min/Max), [ref](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,1239).

Through my digging, I found that `SetCurrentValue` and `SetValue` have two completely different results, and that is: specifying the coercion (`IsInternal` seems to be unused in the case where the bound property is of value type).

My proof is [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx#setcurrentvalue) that states:

> "The SetCurrentValue method is another way to set a property, but it is not in the order of precedence. Instead, SetCurrentValue enables you to change the value of a property without overwriting the source of a previous value. You can use SetCurrentValue any time that you want to set a value without giving that value the precedence of a local value..."

With that being said, moving the `Thumb` of the `Slider` doesn't effect the base value because it is calling `SetCurrentValueInternal`.

Moreover, changing the `Value` manually changes the base value because it calls `SetValue`.  The `ValueProperty` dependency property defines how to coerce using the `CoerceValueCallback` as stated in the last paragraph [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx#animations). In more detail of what's going on in `Slider.Value`,

> Coercion interacts with the base value in such a way that the constraints on coercion are applied as those constraints exist at the time, but the base value is still retained. Therefore, if constraints in coercion are later lifted, the coercion will return the closest value possible to that base value, and potentially the coercion influence on a property will cease as soon as all constraints are lifted.

Of course I read further, [Dependency Property Callbacks and Validation - Advanced Coercion and Callback Scenarios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745795(v=vs.100).aspx#Advanced) and found this:

> For instance, in the Min/Max/Current scenario, you could choose to have Minimum and Maximum be user settable. If so, you might need to coerce that Maximum is always greater than Minimum and vice versa. But if that coercion is active, and Maximum coerces to Minimum, it leaves Current in an unsettable state, because it is dependent on both and is constrained to the range between the values, which is zero. Then, if Maximum or Minimum are adjusted, Current will seem to "follow" one of the values, because the desired value of Current is still stored and is attempting to reach the desired value as the constraints are loosened.

In conclusion, I think this is as-designed in `Slider` because it is coded in such a way that `Value` must always be in between `Minimum` and `Maximum`.  The `Value` will follow the `Maximum` property, and when constraints are lifted (the current value is in range of the base value) the value property will return to its original value.

Lastly, IMO WPF designed the slider this way because WPF goes hand in hand with data binding.  I assume they designed under the assumption that developers would take full advantage of data-binding and would implement the logic to prevent invalid values from being used.

Comment: That's actually a really good workaround. Do you think this is actually a bug in WPF?

Comment: @TimPohlmann Not sure its a bug. It changed its value "automatically" and then set it back when the user hadn't modified the slider value but had changed the min/max settings. Seems like its at least defensible behavior, if not 100% intutiive.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET But for what good reason would it prioritize programmatically set values over values set by a user? This really smells like a bug to me. At the very leasts it's an undocumented behavior. Then again, the msdn page for Minimum and Maxmimum don't even mention, that they might adjust Value if necessary.

Comment: @TimPohlmann Perhaps I'm mis-reading the answer, but I think the user setting it would modify the internal value. Regardless, there is *plenty* of undocumented behavior. Thats what SO is for :)

Comment: @TimPohlmann I think this may be a bug.  I'm going to post a question on SO and see what it comes up with.  You might be able to do the same, seeing as our approach to changing the values will be different--my question will be in MVVM form.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET As shown in my example, it clearly ignores user input.

Comment: @NETscape What do you mean exactly? This question is on SO already.

Comment: @TimPohlmann see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060975/slider-value-does-not-update-after-changing-minimum-and-maximum

Comment: @TimPohlmann see edits. sorry for any misunderstanding. I've been looking at RangeBase, Slider, and DependencyObject for way too long now >.<  Basically, we know that the issue is that sliding the thumb doesn't set the value the same way calling `MySlider.Value` does, and we won't know what is actually going on until we see the internals of that function.

Comment: @NETscape Your example in the edit is basically the same as the one I posted in my new theory. The core problem is that moving the Slider is not actually setting the base value. It is set by the programmatically call of `MySlider.Value = 1`, though. You can confirm that, by changing it to `MySlider.Value = 3` (Slider will always jump back to 3 instead of 1 now). This looks pretty clearly like a bug to me.
Btw: Can you not just look in the source for `SetCurrentValueInternal` by using Reflector? That's what I did to take a closer look at the `Slider`class.

Comment: @NETscape I found the source code for `SetCurrentValueInternal`:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,3ce192f6633decc8

Comment: @TimPohlmann you might consider it a bug, but that's what Microsoft may have intended it to do. I would guess one of their reasons would be it's too expensive to coerce the value every time the slider moves since there is so many value changed events happening during the slide gesture. I would probably consider it a bug myself, but who are we to Microsoft? Hopefully you can plan around this and effectively control your slider. If not there is always the option to roll out your own :D

Comment: @NETscape But I'm not talking about coercion! I'm talking about the fact, that moving the Slider does not set the base value. Your reasoning might be true nonetheless, though.
How would I report this as a bug to Microsoft?

Comment: Coercion needs to happen in order to update the value properly...CoerceValueCallback is not getting called on every value changed event during sliding like it does when you change Maximum/Minimum. So you kind of can't avoid talking about this issue without talking about coercion. You can send a sample solution into them and explain the issues at http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @NETscape: To sum it all up: Slider is not supposed to be used without binding and can cause weird behaviour in that situation. Thanks for your work!